# How can I measure network latency of an Win32 application?

Tags: networking, latency

I have a Win32 application that connects to a server (whose IP is known) on specific ports.

Is there a way to constantly monitor the latency (in milliseconds) of the packets send and received, and have an indication of how how many packets have been dropped, ideally graphically?

Answer (score 1):

Latency is a property of a link between two things, not just one application.

You probably want a network sniffer, perhaps as part of your application.  Without looking at the network your app will get an abstracted view of things like tcp connections, and can't see things like dropped packets.